# May someone help me with a functions questions?

Tags: functions, real-numbers

I was wondering if someone could help me with this question. It is genuinely not homework, it is extra work set by my angry asian mum, and I am desperately in need of help for just this one question. I hope someone can save my life or will get a beating from my angry Asian mum. I $100%$ guarantee that you will say that this is school homework, for that matter I am only $11$ years old already doing secondary school/ high school (that is what you Americans call it, I presume). So please just not disregard this question and say "it is homework" or my my mum will genuinely hit me for not completing all my extracurricular maths work (btw I get a crap ton of work worth about $12$ hours every day).

Anyways that is besides the point, here is the only **one** maths question that I am desperately in need for help. Please save me by just helping me with one question☺

$$f(x)=x^2, g(x)=x-6$$

Solve the equation $fg(x)=g^{-1}(x)$

x=

Thanks in advance, fellow mathematicians.

Comment: How can we solve an equation if the variables $f,g$ are given?

Comment: Well, just go step by step.  First of all, does $fg$ mean the product $f(x)\times g(x)$ or does it mean the composition $f\circ g(x)$?  Either way, I assume you are looking for a value $x_0$ such that the two sides are equal for that particular value, yes?

Comment: @lulu $g^{-1}(x)=x+6$ so whether it is product or composition we will not get an equality. (This might be a troll question, though I'm not sure)

Comment: @Yanko I think (but am not sure) that the OP is looking for a particular value of $x$ that solves that equation.

Comment: @Yanko I think the OP is trying to solve for $x$

Comment: @lulu Ah this makes much more sense. Thanks lulu and saulspatz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume that $fg$ denotes the composition $f\circ g$ because, in this case, using the product makes for a cubic equation with no convenient roots.

So, assuming I have it right, you are asked to solve the equation $$f\circ g(x)=g^{-1}(x)$$

Now, for the left hand:  $$f\circ g(x)=f(g(x))=g(x)^2=(x-6)^2$$

While, for the right hand, $$g^{-1}(x)=x+6$$

So you want to solve the quadratic equation $$(x-6)^2=x+6$$

I assume you know the Quadratic Formula? If so, you can just expand this out and solve in the usual way. Hint:  The roots are pleasant, so you can also just factor the quadratic by inspection.

Comment: Thanks my friend.

Answer (score 0):

$g^{-1}(x)=x+6$. Then, $$(fg)(x)=x^2(x-6)=x+6=g^{-1}(x)$$ which implies that $$x^3-6x^2-x-6=0.$$ But the roots aren't very nice, just see here [by using Wolfram:Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=roots%20of%20x%5E3-6x%5E2-x-6).

If by $fg(x)$ you mean $(f\circ g)(x)$, you obtain $$(f\circ g)(x)=f(x-6)=(x-6)^2=x+6=g^{-1}(x),$$ thus $$x^2-13x+30=0$$ which you can solve using pq-formula and obtain $x=3$ and $x=10$ as solutions.

Comment: Thanks also, truly a wonderful person

Comment: @JieGao If your question was successfully answered, please consider accepting one of the answers.